# Tensorflow pip3 gpu not running

Tags: python, pip, anaconda, tensorflow

I tried to use TensorFlow without virutalenv or docker. Just with pip3. My classifier works in Docker, but it wast just to painful to launch that every time I wanted to do something.  This is my error:

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/home/alvar/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 41, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.pywrap_tensorflow_internal import *
  File "/home/alvar/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 28, in <module>
    _pywrap_tensorflow_internal = swig_import_helper()
  File "/home/alvar/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 24, in swig_import_helper
    _mod = imp.load_module('_pywrap_tensorflow_internal', fp, pathname, description)
  File "/home/alvar/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/imp.py", line 242, in load_module
    return load_dynamic(name, filename, file)
  File "/home/alvar/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/imp.py", line 342, in load_dynamic
    return _load(spec)
ImportError: libcusolver.so.8.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "label_image.py", line 3, in <module>
    import tensorflow as tf
  File "/home/alvar/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/__init__.py", line 24, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python import *
  File "/home/alvar/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/__init__.py", line 49, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python import pywrap_tensorflow
  File "/home/alvar/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 52, in <module>
    raise ImportError(msg)
ImportError: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/alvar/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 41, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.pywrap_tensorflow_internal import *
  File "/home/alvar/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 28, in <module>
    _pywrap_tensorflow_internal = swig_import_helper()
  File "/home/alvar/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 24, in swig_import_helper
    _mod = imp.load_module('_pywrap_tensorflow_internal', fp, pathname, description)
  File "/home/alvar/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/imp.py", line 242, in load_module
    return load_dynamic(name, filename, file)
  File "/home/alvar/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/imp.py", line 342, in load_dynamic
    return _load(spec)
ImportError: libcusolver.so.8.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory


Failed to load the native TensorFlow runtime.
```

This is my code:

```
import os, sys
import urllib.request
import tensorflow as tf

os.environ['TF_CPP_MIN_LOG_LEVEL'] = '2'

print("\n")

# get image
file_name = "new_flower.jpg"
req = urllib.request.urlopen(sys.argv[1])
urllib.request.urlretrieve('http://example.com/big.zip', file_name)


# Read in the image_data
image_data = tf.gfile.FastGFile(file_name, 'rb').read()

# Loads label file, strips off carriage return
label_lines = [line.rstrip() for line
                   in tf.gfile.GFile("retrained_labels.txt")]

# Unpersists graph from file
with tf.gfile.FastGFile("retrained_graph.pb", 'rb') as f:
    graph_def = tf.GraphDef()
    graph_def.ParseFromString(f.read())
    tf.import_graph_def(graph_def, name='')

with tf.Session() as sess:
    # Feed the image_data as input to the graph and get first prediction
    softmax_tensor = sess.graph.get_tensor_by_name('final_result:0')

    predictions = sess.run(softmax_tensor, \
             {'DecodeJpeg/contents:0': image_data})

    # Sort to show labels of first prediction in order of confidence
    top_k = predictions[0].argsort()[-len(predictions[0]):][::-1]

    for node_id in top_k:
        human_string = label_lines[node_id]
        score = predictions[0][node_id]
        print('%s (score = %.5f)' % (human_string, score))


print("\n")
```

Python 3.5.2 :: Anaconda 4.2.0 (64-bit)

Comment: What version of cuda library and cudnn are you using? I think tensorflow is not compatible with some versions

Comment: @VíctorM Cuda: 7.5, V7.5.17 
how do install CuDNN?

Comment: There are a lof of pages with excellent tutorials. I think tensorflow still hasn't added support for those versions of Cuda and CuDNN. The CuDNN library is on the NVIDIA developers page, you just have to register and you can download it :)

Comment: @VíctorM Thanks. I managed to install cuddn. Unforutnally the worng version, 7.5. I installed 8.0 but nvcc -V says it's still version 7.5. How do i fix this?

Comment: As far as I know tensorflow supports the lastest version of cudnn. You should try the cudnn 6 version